# How position a View to the right inside a Toolbart without hiding the title?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm using the Toolbar widget of appcompat v21.

Without hiding the toolbar title I want to add some views (ie: textview, button) to the content of the toolbar.

By default they are positioned to the left, but I need to put them to the right. I managed to do it with a RelativeLayout. The problem is that the RelativeLayout takes all the toolbar's space and the title is not visible anymore.

There is a way to do it without hide the title?